# AngularJS tutorial Thinkster.io chapter 7

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebasesimplelogin

### UPDATE: The tutorial was updated and the following question really no longer applies

---

Learning about AngularJS from the site thinkster.io (free ebook). But at the moment i'm stuck at [chapter 7 - Creating your own user data using firebase](http://www.thinkster.io/angularjs/4DYrJRxTyT/7-creating-your-own-user-data-using-firebase). This is an tutorial about angularjs that works with firebase.

I have wrote all the code according to the site, but i'm getting these console errors when I want to register a user. It will create the user (in firebase -simplelogin), but not the user object (in firebase - data).:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
at Object.User.create (http://localhost:9000/scripts/services/user.js:46:19)
at http://localhost:9000/scripts/controllers/auth.js:32:22
etc.
```

This is the code (same as the site), the error is in the create() function and talks about the users.$save() function, snippet of User.create():

```
users.$save(username).then(function () {
    setCurrentUser(username);
});
```

**Complete code of user.js:**

```js
news.factory("User", function ($firebase, FIREBASE_URL, $rootScope, $log) {
    var reference, users, User;

    reference = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL + "users");
    users = $firebase(reference);

    function setCurrentUser(username) {
        $rootScope.currentUser = User.findByUsername(username);
    }

    $rootScope.$on("$firebaseSimpleLogin:login", function (event, authUser) {
        var query = $firebase(reference.startAt(authUser.uid).endAt(authUser.uid));

        query.$on("loaded", function () {
            setCurrentUser(query.$getIndex()[0]);
        });
    });

    $rootScope.$on("$firebaseSimpleLogin:logout", function () {
        delete $rootScope.currentUser;
    });

    User = {
        create: function (authUser, username) {
            users[username] = {
                md5_hash: authUser.md5_hash,
                username: username,
                "$priority": authUser.uid
            };

            $log.debug(users);

            users.$save(username).then(function () {
                setCurrentUser(username);
            });
        },
        findByUsername: function (username) {
            if (username) {
                return users.$child(username);
            }
        },
        getCurrent: function () {
            return $rootScope.currentUser;
        },
        signedIn: function () {
            return $rootScope.currentUser !== undefined;
        }
    };

    return User;
});
```

**Edit 1:**
Registering a user now works, got it working (saving in firebase, simple login and data):

```js
users = $firebase(reference).$asObject();
```

Notice the users.save() function:

```
        create: function (authUser, username) {
            users[username] = {
                md5_hash: authUser.md5_hash,
                username: username,
                $priority: authUser.uid
            };

            $log.debug(users);

            users.$save().then(function () {
                setCurrentUser(users);
            });
        },
```

```js
        findByUsername: function (users) {
            if (users) {
                return users;
            }
        },
```

**Edit 2:**
Now I get an error at the log in of the user (see below), when I want to log in, I get an error on this this function, query.$on():

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
at http://localhost:9000/scripts/services/user.js:26:19
```

```js
    $rootScope.$on("$firebaseSimpleLogin:login", function (event, authUser) {
        var query = $firebase(reference.startAt(authUser.uid).endAt(authUser.uid));

        query.$on("loaded", function () {
            setCurrentUser(query.$getIndex()[0]);
        });
    });
```

What is wrong now?

Comment: What version of AngularFire are you using?

Comment: wow. those are the only problems you had with section 7? consider yourself lucky. i'm going to be posting a question tomorrow with all the roadblocks I've hit. most are in the `user.js` service but I also have one in the `nav.js` controller.

Comment: @s3z : I also had some problems with other sections, but these were the annoying ones. The free ebook is just not complete/correct with the current versions.

Comment: @David: angularfire = v0.8.2, firebase = v1.0.21

Comment: @AnnaSmother exactly and judging by ThinksterIO's Twitter, looks like they've abandoned ship. Last (re)tweet was from March 2014.

Comment: Thinkster is hard at work on the next iteration of their Angular tutorial and it is coming along nicely. @David and I had a brief chat with them just a week ago. It's not easy to keep such great material up to date with a fast moving mark like AngularFire.

Comment: @Kato: Thanks for the information, but they could at least update their website, telling the tutorial won't work atm. and they are working on it (they had an entire month). Almost every chapter, from the moment you integrate firebase, has flaws. Chapter 7 and 8 are the worst and I don't always agree on how they build up the data structure in firebase (but that is just me ;) ). On a positive note: I like that this tutorial is free and apparently a lot of people (for v0.8) has enjoyed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an answer on edit 2: I have used firebase(ref), query.$loaded and searched for the right object, that's it. Maybe someone have an different answer, please post them :).

I have finally completed chapter 07!

In general (solution for Edit 2):

```
    $rootScope.$on("$firebaseSimpleLogin:login", function (event, authUser) {
        var query = $firebase(reference).$asObject();

        query.$loaded(function (result) {
            angular.forEach(result, function (key) {
                if (key.md5_hash === authUser.md5_hash) {
                    setCurrentUser(key);
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

This is not the ideal solution, but the free ebook (atm of writing) is far from ideal. Then again, these kind of situations helps you to understand a little bit more about the firebase api and how it works with angular. But can be frustrated at times, when you just want to go through the tutorial ;).

Note! I have saved the User object and pass the User object to the findUsername() and setCurrentUser() functions instead of just the user.username.

You can also use the native array function, like some().

Comment: can you post your code solution under your your second update? I am confused by your answer. I am stuck at this part too.

Comment: Thanks but I don't understand it. I am actually getting this TypeError as well as another one right after registering a new user. I've posted my issue here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25667143/typeerror-undefined-is-not-a-function-with-firebase-and-angularjs-thinksterio Any ideas?

Comment: Thank you. The update to this answer solved the second TypeError :)

Answer (score 0):

I think your system uses the newer version of Angularfire (version>= 0.8). Which means for running through loops that are arrays ...you need to attach `.$asArray()` at the end of the user definition field. Check the updates of Firebase.