# TypeError: undefined is not a function with Firebase and AngularJS (ThinksterIO Tutorial Chapter 7)

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire, firebasesimplelogin

### Update

**The tutorial has been updated and the question is now outdated**

---

I've run into multiple issues with the Thinkster.io AngularJS Tutorial: Learn to build Modern Webapps   [Chapter 7. Creating your own user data using firebase](http://www.thinkster.io/angularjs/4DYrJRxTyT/7-creating-your-own-user-data-using-firebase).

The first had to do with saving a new user to the Firebase Forge which thankfully was solved by Anna Smother in her SO post [AngularJS tutorial Thinkster.io chapter 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25633141/angularjs-tutorial-thinkster-io-chapter-7) but now I am getting two TypeErrors after registering a new user. I will explain what happens when I register a new user:

1. I fill out the registration form
2. I click Register
3. I see my new user object logged to the console
4. I get logged in
5. 2 `TypeError: undefined is not a function` errors appear in the console

[image]

---

### 1st TypeError: undefined is not a function

So looking at the first error we see 3 places being pointed to in my `user.js`

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Object.User.findByUsername (http://localhost:9000/scripts/services/user.js:37:18)
    at setCurrentUser (http://localhost:9000/scripts/services/user.js:8:33)
    at http://localhost:9000/scripts/services/user.js:32:5
```

The first place in my code that the first error points to is line 37, column 18 which is the beginning of $child`in the`findByUsername` function

```
findByUsername: function (username) {
  if (username) {
    return users.$child(username);
  }
},
```

From there it points to line 8, column 33 which is the beginning of the `findByUsername` method call

```
function setCurrentUser(username) {
  $rootScope.currentUser = User.findByUsername(username);
}
```

And lastly it points to line 32, column 5 which is the beginning of the `setCurrentUser` method call

```
  users.$save().then(function() {
    setCurrentUser(username);
  });
```

---

### 2nd TypeError: undefined is not a function

The second TypeError points at only one place in `user.js`

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at http://localhost:9000/scripts/services/user.js:14:9
```

which is line 14, column 9 at the beginning of the `$on` method call

```
query.$on('loaded', function () {
  setCurrentUser(query.$getIndex()[0]);
});
```

Any ideas on why I'm getting these two TypeErrors?

---

### FILES

**user.js** service

```
'use strict';

app.factory('User', function ($firebase, FIREBASE_URL, $rootScope) {
  var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL + 'users');
  var users = $firebase(ref).$asObject();

  function setCurrentUser(username) {
    $rootScope.currentUser = User.findByUsername(username);
  }

  $rootScope.$on('$firebaseSimpleLogin:login', function (e, authUser) {
    var query = $firebase(ref.startAt(authUser.uid).endAt(authUser.uid));

    query.$on('loaded', function () {
      setCurrentUser(query.$getIndex()[0]);
    });
  });

  $rootScope.$on('$firebaseSimpleLogin:logout', function() {
    delete $rootScope.currentUser;
  });

  var User = {
    create: function (authUser, username) {
      users[username] = {
        /*jshint camelcase: false */
        md5_hash: authUser.md5_hash,
        username: username,
        $priority: authUser.uid
      };
      users.$save().then(function() {
        setCurrentUser(username);
      });
    },
    findByUsername: function (username) {
      if (username) {
        return users.$child(username);
      }
    },
    getCurrent: function () {
      return $rootScope.currentUser;
    },
    signedIn: function () {
      return $rootScope.currentUser !== undefined;
    }
  };

  return User;
});
```

---

**auth.js** controller

```
'use strict';

app.controller('AuthCtrl',
  function ($scope, $location, Auth, User) {
    if (Auth.signedIn()) {
      $location.path('/');
    }

    $scope.$on('firebaseSimpleLogin:login', function() {
      $location.path('/');
    });

    $scope.login = function() {
      Auth.login($scope.user).then(function() {
        $location.path('/');
      }, function(error) {
        $scope.error = error.toString();
      });
    };

    $scope.register = function () {
      Auth.register($scope.user).then(function (authUser) {
        User.create(authUser, $scope.user.username);
        $location.path('/');
        Auth.login($scope.user);
        console.log(authUser);
      }, function(error) {
        $scope.error = error.toString();
      });
    };
  });
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJS tutorial Thinkster.io chapter 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25633141/angularjs-tutorial-thinkster-io-chapter-7)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check my solution in Edit 1: I have update the code, this should take away your error when you are registering?

Since version 0.8 of angularfire, they have taken out $child() and $on(), I will update my solution for edit 2, tonight (when I get home).

[AngularJS tutorial Thinkster.io chapter 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25633141/angularjs-tutorial-thinkster-io-chapter-7)

Also check this out:

[AngularFire api](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html)

Comment: Yes the solution on your Edit: 1 solved the first TypeError. I'm looking forward to how you dealt with the second one. I looked at the API and actually saw a code example for the "Login in related events" section and they used `$rootScope.$on()` in it believe it or not https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/api.html#angularfire-firebasesimplelogin-login-related-events I let them know about that.

Comment: @s3z: I have updated my second edit (Edit 2), you can check it out.

Comment: Thanks again Anna. So after implementing the two fixes I am getting 2 new TypeErrors (occuring in the post.js service) both related to `.$child()` and `.$on()` again. They occur when I submit a post and try to delete a post. I tried to figure out how to solve them based on your previous fixes but, I just don't know enough JS to work through problems at this level. I've included these two new TypeErrors in Update 1 of this post as well my post.js code. If you have time could you take a look? I'd appreciate it greatly :)

Comment: @s3z: I recommend to open a new post, because these are new problems. Besides that, I have done it the easy way. Since they removed $child() and $on() on the $firebase() object, you can **not** use them. If you are using an $firebase(ref), for example: var postref = $firebase(ref); You can call postref.$ref().child() or you can use var ref = new Firebase(url); ref.child("posts").chid(postId).remove(). And for the $on(), just use $loaded() (in this case).

Comment: Ok I opened a new post here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25692853/typeerror-undefined-is-not-a-function-while-submitting-deleting-post-using-an So I read your explanation on what to do but I realize I would need the actual full code example to really start to understand it.